# React not re-rendering on changing array within state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState[{name:"abc", gender: "male", experience: ["a","b","c"]}];
```

I have a display function for experience

```
const display= () => {
  let items = data.experience;
  return items.map((val,ind) => {
    return(<li key={ind}>{val}</li>);
  });
}
```

**If I delete a value of experience, my state changes with the new items array but my component is not updating with the updated items, how can I overcome this issue**

Delete Function: (It is working perfectly and state changes, but component is not rerendering new state)

```
  const deleteExperience = (ind) => {
    let newData = data;
    let experiences = newData.experience.filter((val, id) => id !== ind);
    newData.experience = experiences;
    setData(newData);
  };
```

Comment: I have fixed it, the issue was  in delete function: 

````
 const deleteExperience = (ind) => {
    let newData = data;
    let experiences = newData.experience.filter((val, id) => id !== ind);
    newData.experience = experiences;
    setData(newData);
  };
````
Correction (object spread should be used): 
````
 const deleteExperience = (ind) => {
    let newData = {...data};
    let experiences = newData.experience.filter((val, id) => id !== ind);
    newData.experience = experiences;
    setData(newData);
  };
````

Comment: If that solves your issue, please add your comment as an answer to your question and accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this- you can delete like this

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    name: "abc",
    gender: "male",
    experience: ["a", "b", "c"]
  });
  const deleteIt = id => {
    let filtered = data.experience.filter(filt => filt !== id);
    setData({
      ...data,
      experience: filtered
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {data.experience.map(d => (
          <li key={d} onClick={() => deleteIt(d)}>
            <h3>{d}</h3>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-cdn-0e8e2)

Comment: I can delete, my issue is that the state is updating but the component is not re-rendering

Comment: @FahadMahmood your updation function isn't right i think... share your delete function code

Comment: @FahadMahmood you need to update inside state for rerendering component...don't mutate state directly. refer this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5/

Comment: Yeah, it's fixed, I was using = for array cloning

Answer (score 0):

How are you deleting the array? if you are using splice to delete an index.
This will happen sometimes that you call setState before that actual data change in array so try to call setState after a little delay to that operation like setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // call your setState here with new data
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, the issue was in delete function:

```
const deleteExperience = (ind) => { 
    let newData = data;
    let experiences = newData.experience.filter((val, id) => id !== ind); 
    newData.experience = experiences;
    setData(newData); 
};
```

Correction (object spread should be used) as = sign does not create a new array but creates a reference to the original array:

```
const deleteExperience = (ind) => { 
    let newData = {...data};
    let experiences = newData.experience.filter((val, id) => id !== ind); 
    newData.experience = experiences;
    setData(newData); 
};
```